# SQL view with "with check option"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently reading the documentation from Microsoft about views and I am kind of confused on what I read about the "with check option." There isn't any examples provided in the documentation. Can someone make me a simple example? I understand easier with examples.

> CHECK OPTION Forces all data modification statements executed against
>   the view to follow the criteria set within select_statement. When a
>   row is modified through a view, the WITH CHECK OPTION makes sure the
>   data remains visible through the view after the modification is
>   committed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doesn't that mean that you can't make such update via the view, that the row(s) would disappear from the view because of whatever `where` statement you have in the view would not match the row anymore.

View:

```
create view xxx as select * from table where status = 1
```

update using the table (ok):

```
update table set status = 2 where id = 3
```

update using the view (not ok):

```
update xxx set status = 2 where id = 3
```

and if you would do this, it would make the row disappear

Comment: so basically if the row won't be able to be shown after the insert/update/delete from the view, "with check option" won't let me to do the modification right?

Answer (score 8):

Below is an example that shows the `CHECK OPTION` behavior.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1(Col1 int);
CREATE TABLE dbo.Table2(Col2 int);
INSERT INTO dbo.Table1 (Col1) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 (Col2) VALUES(1);
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewWithCheckOption
AS
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table2.Col2
FROM dbo.Table1
JOIN dbo.Table2 ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col2
WITH CHECK OPTION;
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.ViewWithoutCheckOption
AS
SELECT Table1.Col1, Table2.Col2
FROM dbo.Table1
JOIN dbo.Table2 ON Table1.Col1 = Table2.Col2;
GO

SELECT Col1, Col1 FROM dbo.ViewWithoutCheckOption; --returns 1 row
INSERT INTO dbo.ViewWithoutCheckOption(Col1) VALUES(2); --succeeds
SELECT Col1, Col1 FROM dbo.ViewWithoutCheckOption; --still returns 1 row

SELECT Col1, Col1 FROM dbo.ViewWithCheckOption; --returns 1 row
INSERT INTO dbo.ViewWithCheckOption(Col1) VALUES(2); -- fails with error
```

The error returned is:

> Msg 550, Level 16, State 1, Line 30 The attempted insert or update
>   failed because the target view either specifies WITH CHECK OPTION or
>   spans a view that specifies WITH CHECK OPTION and one or more rows
>   resulting from the operation did not qualify under the CHECK OPTION
>   constraint.

Answer (score 5):

Let's understand using the following example

```
CREATE VIEW PortlandAreaAddresses_vw
AS
SELECT AddressID,
AddressLine1,
City,
StateProvinceID,
PostalCode,
ModifiedDate
FROM Person.Address
WHERE PostalCode LIKE ‘970%’
OR PostalCode LIKE ‘971%’
OR PostalCode LIKE ‘972%’
OR PostalCode LIKE ‘986[6-9]%’
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

In this case, if you try to insert a record, CHECK OPTION will enforce to to follow the 4 rules specified for PostalCode

```
WHERE PostalCode LIKE ‘970%’
OR PostalCode LIKE ‘971%’
OR PostalCode LIKE ‘972%’
OR PostalCode LIKE ‘986[6-9]%’
```

That means you can't insert a PostalCode like '19970'

Answer (score 0):

Its actually pretty simple.

The `view` in mysql are created using some select statement.

example: consider following table `empl`.

```
empno   ename       deptno
1       Ross        University
2       Rachel      Sales
3       Monika      Chef
4       Chandler    Managment
5       Joe         Actor
6       Pheobe      Singer
```

we can create a view `myview` in following manner

```
CREATE VIEW myview 
AS 
SELECT empno, ename
FROM empl
WHERE ename LIKE "R%";
```

Let me create another view `myview2` but with `WITH CHECK OPTION`

```
CREATE VIEW myview 
AS 
SELECT empno, ename
FROM empl
WHERE ename LIKE "R%";
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

Now the select statement for both the views is that the `ename` should start with `R`.

Let see what happens if we update the view `myview`.

```
UPDATE myview
SET ename = "David" 
WHERE empno =1;
```

Follwoing will be the output

```
empno   ename       deptno
1       David       University
2       Rachel      Sales
```

However, when we do same with `myview2`

```
UPDATE myview2
SET ename = "David" 
WHERE empno =1;
```

we get an error.

```
ERROR 1369 (HY000): CHECK OPTION failed 'database.myview2'
```

This is becuase the view check the condition that the ename should start with R.